# mpirun OpenFOAM parallel app in gdb

Tags: debugging, parallel-processing, gdb, openmpi

I'm trying to step through an OpenFOAM application (in this case, icoFoam, but this question is in general for any OpenFOAM app).

I'd like to use gdb to step through an analysis running in parallel (let's say, 2 procs).

To simply launch the app in parallel, I type:

```
mpirun -np 2 icoFoam -parallel
```

Now I want to step through it in gdb.  But I'm having trouble launching icoFoam in parallel and debugging it, since I can't figure out how to set a break point before the application begins to execute.

One thing I know I could do is insert a section of code after the MPI_Initialize that waits (and endless loop) until I change some variable in gdb.  Then I'd run the app in parallel, attach a gdb session to each of those PIDs, and happily debug.  But I'd rather not have to alter the OpenFOAM source and recompile.

So, how can I start the application running in parallel, some how get it to stop (like at the beginning of main) and then step through it in gdb?  All without changing the original source code?

Kindest regards,
Madeleine.

Answer (score 1):

[You could try this resource](http://openfoamwiki.net/index.php/HowTo_debugging#gdb)

It looks like the correct command is:

```
mpirunDebug -np 2 xxxFoam -parallel
```